# Is it possible to alias a non aws service with AWS Route 53

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

We have a domain wich is managed on AWS 53.
Is it possible to create an alias record in AWS route 53 to refer to a public IP address (for instance AZURE VM public IP). So that I could use this example "azvm.domain.com" to reference to the Azure VM .

Comment: Not an alias, no, but you can add a plain old A record, or a CNAME to the Azure DNS record.

Comment: Thank you ceejayoz I think i will try the Cname option; Do i have to configure in the VM aswell like this (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/custom-domain) or only on AWS 53